# Is there any forum in codeigniter php?

Tags: codeigniter-2

Is there any forum software based on codeigniter ? free or commercial ?

Comment: what you mean by forum ??

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tried either of these myself but i've heard very good things and you should take the time to investigate them both:

[Dove Forums](https://doveforums.com/)
Dove Forum is fairly new, but growing and seems to have fairly strong support from the Code Igniter community at the moment.

[Pyro CMS](http://pyrocms.com/)
Pyro CMS is made by some of the top contributors to the Code Igniter community and gets alot of plaudits.

It's a fully fledged CMS rather than a forum script, but it has a forum add on which you can download to add that functionality.

Comment: i cannot see any way to contact dove forum peoples

Comment: Try registering and posting on their support forums

http://www.doveforums.com/support/

Comment: It's worth noting that Dove just released a new version and it's awesome. Way better than the original version, it even has a hook based plugins system similar to Wordpress's.

Answer (score 5):

You could check out MyForum (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/MyForum) - it is reasonably simple and I have had very good experiences with it in the past! It's free as well :)

Comment: zip file now is unavailable

Answer (score 2):

Yep http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MyForum/  is nice and you can get all the necessary information about the coding and other practices using codeigniter over here.

Comment: the download link is not available any more...=(

Answer (score 0):

not sure how helpful this is to you now, but Elite Bulletin Board(http://elite-board.us) is switching to CodeIgniter for their next version.

while its still in development, the code is in SVN if you wanted to look at it.